# How to efficiently store a lot of transaction records in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I want to create a system which will get a LOT of transactions, so a typical row will look like this:

```
id, device, country, amount, os
```

The system is perceived to receive around 4 million transactions a day, so in one year, I would have 1 trillion rows of transactional data.

Is there a better way to store this kind of information without slowing down performance and using so much space?.

I must be able to conduct queries such as select transactions where country is USA and os is Android...

Thank you.

Comment: If you really need to store trillions of transactions, and if you won't need to query them very often, then using a NoSQL data store such as Cassandra might be a better option.

Comment: The transactional data will be frequently viewed by our clients

Comment: Can the data be partitioned in any meaningful way such that certain customers would tend to be viewing certain types of data?

Comment: I thought about that, but analytics flexibility is one of the core competencies of this service

Comment: Let's see the typical `SELECTs` (not just the hand-waving you provided).  Will any involve aggregations?  `ORDER BY`?  `LIMIT`?  Will you be deleting data after a year?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: With such a big amount of data, the database design should be oriented to optimize the most frequent queries. Could you please post your `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the most frequent queries?